# Python - detect keypress in shell

Tags: python, shell, keypress, python-idle

Trying to detect and respond to key presses in Python. Am using IDLE and Python 3.3. I have the following code so far

```
import msvcrt

while True:
   inp = ord(msvcrt.getch())

   if (inp != 255):
      print(inp)
```

I have the IF statement because if I just allow the script to throw out the value of 'inp' it just spoons out 255 repeatedly. So I threw in the if statement to respond to anything but 255 and now when run the code does nothing but output the actual keypress character in the shell.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `getch` reads the input immediately, it doesn't wait until you type something. When it doesn't receive any input, it will simply return "\xff" (ordinal 255).

Answer (score 0):

The getch function is designed to work in a console, not in a graphical program.

When you use it in a graphical program it is going to return immediately with \xff.

If you run your program in the reguler python interpreter it will not cause you that problem.

In addition, when you run the loop with the if statement it is running continuously and using a lot more processor time then it needs. In windows the only proper way of doing so is using window messages which sounds like it is overkill for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a [**keyboard**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard) module with many features. You Can Use It In Both *Shell* and *Console*. It Also Detect Key For The Whole Windows.
Install it, perhaps with this command:

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

Then use it in code like:

```
import keyboard #Using module keyboard
while True:  #making a loop
    try:  #used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        if keyboard.is_pressed('a'): #if key 'a' is pressed 
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
            break #finishing the loop
        else:
            pass
    except:
        break  #if user pressed other than the given key the loop will break
```

You can set it to multiple Key Detection:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('a') or keyboard.is_pressed('b') or keyboard.is_pressed('c'):  # and so on
    #then do this
```

When You Install The Module, got to folder:

```
python36-32/Lib/site-packages/keyboard
```

Open File`_keyboard_event.py` in notepad++.
There will be keyboard events.
Not Sure About All Of Them.
Thanks.